# groovy display message while action ended

Tags: multithreading, groovy, concurrency

while action executing, it will render "data is processing" on the page, and now i want to display some message after the action is ended, so how do i suppose to do that?

```
 def reader(){
            def thread = Thread.start{
            //my action coding here
            }

            render "data is processing"


           // thread.end(){
           // render "finished"
           // }

        }
```

Comment: Should't You just put `render.finished` at the very end of `Thread.start` closure?

Comment: What about async? http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/async.html